# FULL OUTER JOIN emulation and aggregate function (e.g. SUM)

Tags: sqlite, join, group-by, common-table-expression, full-outer-join

I have two SQLite tables:

```
CREATE TABLE T_A (year_A INT, amount_A DOUBLE);

  year_A   | amount_A
----------------------
    2020   |    100.0
    2020   |    200.0
    2021   |    300.0
    2021   |    400.0

CREATE TABLE T_B (year_B INT, amount_B DOUBLE);

  year_B   | amount_B
----------------------
    2021   |   1000.0
    2021   |   2000.0
    2022   |   3000.0
    2022   |   4000.0
```

I would like a `VIEW` with the `SUM` of `amount_A` and `amount_B` on every year present either in `T_A` or `T_B`:

View `Sums`

```
  year   | SUM(amount_A) | SUM(amount_B) 
------------------------------------------
  2020   |      300.0    |        0.0    
  2021   |      700.0    |     3000.0    
  2022   |        0.0    |     7000.0
```

If I use an `INNER JOIN` in my query, all I get is a result for `year` 2021.
A `FULL OUTER JOIN` is what I need. As it does not exist in SQLite, I tried to apply [this workaround](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-outer-join/). But I cannot get it work properly as a `SUM` is involved too.

SQLite supports FULL OUTER JOIN since version 3.39.0. I use SQLite through Python 3.10. It's a pain to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link, especially not an off-site link. Quote with credit & format as a quote & relate to your question. PS There is no question in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite supports `FULL OUTER JOIN` since [version 3.39.0](https://sqlite.org/changes.html).

First you must aggregate inside each of the tables and then do a `FULL` join on the aggregated results:

```
WITH 
  cte_A AS (SELECT year_A, SUM(amount_A) AS sum_A FROM T_A GROUP BY year_A),
  cte_B AS (SELECT year_B, SUM(amount_B) AS sum_B FROM T_B GROUP BY year_B)
SELECT COALESCE(a.year_A, b.year_B) year,
       COALESCE(a.sum_A, 0) AS sum_A,
       COALESCE(b.sum_B, 0) AS sum_B
FROM cte_A AS a FULL OUTER JOIN cte_B AS b
ON b.year_B = a.year_A
ORDER BY year;
```

For previous versions of SQLite use `UNION ALL` and then aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT year_A AS year, amount_A, 0 AS amount_B FROM T_A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT year_B, 0, amount_B FROM T_B
)
SELECT year,
       SUM(amount_A) AS sum_A,
       SUM(amount_B) AS sum_B
FROM cte
GROUP BY year
ORDER BY year;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_3m-_HcQ).